# Is there a way to enhance security in Google Forms by automatically replacing answers with asterisks or dots?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-forms-api

Good day. I created a section in google form and their enter the password before entering the whole form. Its possible to autoreplace the password their enter to asterisk or dot? My reason I dont want to show the details answer in password section. Thank you.

[Password Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4z7V.png)

Comment: Google forms are not recommended to get passwords and sensitive information. Therefore there is no native function or settings that can be applied to accomplish your desired result. However, work around this has already been widely known. You have to deploy a web app that can take a password and paste it on the same sheet where you are getting your data.  You can start getting into the right direction by reading through this article: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web.